# Processing.js HashMap

Tags: javascript, java, processing, processing.js

I'm having issues iterating over a HashMap in Processing.js. When calling the iterator, while(it.hasNext()) is never entered.

As a sanity check, I tried to skip the iterator and instead convert the keys to an array and iterate over those by index. That didn't work either. I printed out the following:

```
myHashMap.size();          // outputs 4
myHashMap.keySet().size(); // outputs 4
myHashMap.keySet().toArray().length; // outputs 0
```

I would expect the final line to also output 4, as they previous calls did. Am I understanding something incorrectly? Thanks!

---

EDIT

Here is a full example of the problem I was running into. Turned out to be a problem with using a float in my HashCode, though I still don't understand why that causes a mismatch in elements when converting the keySet to an array.

```
class Vertex {
    float x;
    float y;

    public Vertex(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = ((hash + x) << 5) - (hash + x);    
        hash = ((hash + y) << 5) - (hash + y);    
        return hash
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {    
        Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;    
        return (x == obj.x && y == obj.y);    
    }

}

HashMap<Vertex, String> tmp = new HashMap<Vertex, String>();                
Vertex a = new Vertex(1.1, 2.2);    
Vertex b = new Vertex(1, 1);    
tmp.put(a, "A");                         
tmp.put(b, "B");                         

println("1, " + tmp.size());                      // outputs 2         
println("2, " + tmp.keySet().size());             // outputs 2
println("3, " + tmp.keySet().toArray().length);   // outputs 1
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows us exactly the code you're running. Note that this should just be a few lines, just enough for us to copy and paste to get the same results, but not your whole sketch!

Comment: This code works fine for me: `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("one", "A");
map.put("two", "B");
map.put("three", "C");

println(map.size());
println(map.keySet().toArray().length);`

Comment: Ah, thanks Kevin! Sorry about the incomplete example. You're response led me to debug from a lower level. My problem turned out to be that the keys in my HashMap were objects, and the hashCode I was creating for those objects was failing due to an incorrect use of a float. I still don't understand why the calls to keySet().size() and keySet().toArray().length resulted in different values. I'll post an updated code sample with what I was really running into in case anyone is interested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally figured it out. This took some head-scratching. Nice question.

Moral of the story: I think you've stumbled into a bit of weirdness with the `hashCode()` function. The `hashCode()` function has to return an `int` value, but you're returning a `float` value.

**To fix your problem, cast the `hash` value into an `int` before returning it!**

```
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash = ((hash + x) << 5) - (hash + x);    
    hash = ((hash + y) << 5) - (hash + y);   
    return (int)hash;
  }
```

That might seem strange and unnecessary, so here's a longer explanation:

Notice that `x` and `y` are `float` values, so when you use them in your `hash` calculations, the result becomes a `float` as well. You can prove this by printing out the value of `hash` before you return it.

Java would complain about this. You can prove this by switching to Java mode and trying to run your program. But JavaScript isn't as strict with its types, so it lets your shoot yourself in the foot. Something I commonly do is program in Java mode to get its error checking, and then deploy using JavaScript mode.

Anyway, inside the `HashMap` class, the result of the `hashCode()` function is eventually used as an index in an array. You can view that yourself in the [Processing.js](https://github.com/jeresig/processing-js/blob/master/processing.js) source file:

```
//this is in the HashMap class
function getBucketIndex(key) {
        var index = virtHashCode(key) % buckets.length;
        return index < 0 ? buckets.length + index : index;
}

function virtHashCode(obj) {
    if (obj.hashCode instanceof Function) {
      return obj.hashCode();
    }
   //other code omitted to keep this short
}
```

And that might be fine, because strangely enough JavaScript is okay with decimal places in array indexes. But the problem is the implementation of `HashSet`'s `Iterator`:

```
function Iterator(conversion, removeItem) {
    var bucketIndex = 0;
    var itemIndex = -1;
    var endOfBuckets = false;
    var currentItem;

    function findNext() {
      while (!endOfBuckets) {
        ++itemIndex;
        if (bucketIndex >= buckets.length) {
          endOfBuckets = true;
        } else if (buckets[bucketIndex] === undef || itemIndex >= buckets[bucketIndex].length) {
          itemIndex = -1;
          ++bucketIndex;
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    //more code
```

Check out that `findNext()` function. It's looping through the indexes of the array, but it's incrementing by one each time. So any keys that are put into decimal-place indexes will be skipped!

That's why your iterator skips one of your objects (the one with a decimal place in the value returned from `hashCode()`). And that's why `toArray()` fails as well, since that function uses an `Iterator` under the hood.

I wouldn't really call this a bug, since the problem is caused by returning a `float` from a function that says it will return an `int`. JavaScript doesn't really need `hashCode()` functions the same way Java does, so this implementation of `HashMap` and `Iterator` are pretty reasonable. But you do have to make sure you're returning an `int` from the `hashCode()` function.

By the way, here's a smaller example if you feel like playing around:

```
class Thing {
  int myThing;

  public Thing(int myThing) {
    this.myThing = myThing;
  }
  
  public int hashCode(){
    return myThing;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {    
    Thing other = (Thing) obj;    
    return (myThing == other.myThing);
  }
}

void setup() {
         
  HashMap<Thing, String> map = new HashMap<Thing, String>();
  map.put(new Thing(1), "A");
  map.put(new Thing(2.5), "B"); //uh oh!
  map.put(new Thing(3), "C");
  println("1, " + map.size());                      // outputs 3         
  println("2, " + map.keySet().size());             // outputs 3
  println("3, " + map.keySet().toArray().length);   // outputs 2
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! That took some tracking down :) Would never have thought of that, but incrementing based on an integer index of course makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion on developing in Java mode, definitely going to go for that. Thanks for solving the mystery, and.. the more you know!